# Dockerized ThingsBoard + dockerized PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, thingsboard

I launch a container running PostgreSQL with the command:

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 -d -it -e POSTGRES_USER='postgres' -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD='postgres' -e POSTGRES_DB='thingsboard' --name postgres postgres
```

Then, I launch ThingsBoard providing some environment variables to use the PostgreSQL database:

```
docker run -it -p 9090:9090 -p 1883:1883 -p 5683:5683/udp -v ~/.mytb-data:/data -v ~/.mytb-logs:/var/logs/thingsboard --name thingsboard --restart always -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://<MY_LOCAL_IP>:5432/thingsboard -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=postgres thingsboard/tb-postgres
```

where `<MY_LOCAL_IP>` is my IP address on the local network. I checked PostgreSQL, which actually binds to `<MY_LOCAL_IP>:5432` (verified through PGAdmin).
The `thingsboard` container returns an error:

[image]

I expect ThingsBoard itself to create the tables in the `thingsboard` database, but it seems that it doesn't appen so. Any guess on the possible cause of this error? Thanks.

Comment: Here you see a screenshot from Windows 10, the same error occurs - as expected - on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is given by the volumes: `mytb-data` and `mytb-logs` have been created before and are not empty. The containers work as long as we launch `thingsboard` with:

```
docker run -it -p 9090:9090 -p 1883:1883 -p 5683:5683/udp --name thingsboard --restart always -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://<MY_LOCAL_IP>:5432/thingsboard -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=postgres thingsboard/tb-postgres
```